# Simple math formula to make a number go 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and so on

Tags: math, equation

math is not my strongest side so please someone help me with this formula:
I have an ascending variabel y that goes to infinity.

When:

```
y < 100 I want x = 1,
100 >= y < 200 I want x = 2,
200 >= y < 300 I want x = 4,
300 >= y < 400 I want x = 8
400 >= y < 500 I want x = 16
```

and so on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a programming problem? What language do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 2 ^ (y / 100)
```

or if y is not an integer (which would amount to integer division).

```
x = 2 ^ Floor(y / 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
 2 ^ ( y / 100 )
```

Note that this uses integer division. So `250 / 100 == 2`.